# Fine uploader does not allow to choose multiple files in IE8 and IE9 any more

Tags: fine-uploader

It worked perfectly until soon in every browser including IE8, IE9 and IE10.
Now in IE8 and IE9 user is unable to choose multiple files. It may choose only one and it is uploaded fine. IE10 works fine too.
I checked the official fine-uploader demo page: *http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-demo.html*, it works the same(in IE8 and IE9 does not allow to choose multiple files).
So the most probable problem is the IE but my question is 
**'Is it fixable?'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was NEVER possible to choose multiple files at once in IE9 or older in Fine Uploader (or any other upload tool that doesn't rely on Flash or Java).  The reason for this is the lack of support for the "multiple" attribute on file input elements.  The same restriction exists for all builds of Android, if I remember correctly.  Again, this is a browser limitation, not a Fine Uploader limitation.  In IE9 and older, you will need to select files one at a time, and you cannot submit them via drag and drop.